# remount system form native application

Tags: android, system, mount

I have a native C program that calls **system("mount -o rw,remount /system")** in order to mount the system writable. It has suid bit set and is set to chown root:root so every user can call it and /system will be mounted writable.
(I know ... this is for testing and understanding so please do not discuss security aspects)

This program works when I call it in the console no matter what user I "su" to. mount shows rw for /system.
When I let my java app call this program using **p = new ProcessBuilder().command("/system/app/testmounter").start();** nothing is remounted. But there is no error returned.

Now I launched a Process with "mount" and read the result in my java app right after the call to my testmounter. Is says /system is rw. At the same time the console says it is ro.

What's happening here? Is the mount state depending on the process that calls mount? That appears strange to me.

Comment: Does your device have **root** privileges?

Comment: yes there is su but I want do solve this without getting superuser rights for the app. Interestingly there are other threads about that. They say the mount rw seems to be immediately reset after setting. Or it is valid for this one session only. Can someone confirm this behaviour?

Comment: Android has been using process-unique mounts for a release or two now (you'll see for example that the external storage is in different places for an app vs adb), but you'd have to investigate in detail to figure out if this applies to what you are trying to do.

Comment: OMG really?? When I do that from adb or console over putty (different users, shell and root) then the rw mount applies to both. But that concept is interesting.
What I don't understand then, shouldn't the mount be visible for the root user in the shell when the mount is done from a program that is launched from user u0_axx but the program runs as root?